# How can I choose a legible color to draw text on a bar in a d3js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, visualization

I have a bar chart done using d3 and I would like to put text on the bars. How can I choose the most legible color for the text e.g. white for dark bars and black for others? I can't choose the bar colors but I do know what color each bar is when I append the text.

PS: The possible duplicate is a general Javascript solution, its much easier with d3.

Comment: There is a solution there that I will look into but nothing on how to do this specifically with d3js.

Comment: I assumed you knew how to set the text/color , based on your question - (*" I can't choose the bar colors but I do know what color each bar is when I append the text"*). Anyway, I started putting together an answer when I cam across that linked answer. Maybe the fiddle helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/rvvy2nfd/

Answer (score 7):

The d3 specific solution to this is simple:

```
var color = .. function giving color of the bar ..
text.style("fill", function(d) { return d3.hsl(color(d)).l > 0.5 ? "#000" : "#fff" })
```

Thanks @Jamiec for the link.